# String array in methods and printing

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods, return

I need to figure out what this method does. I don't understand this part specifically. I also would like to know how to print the answer. What I have done just prints a memory address I think.

```
tmp[i] = a[i].length();
```

Here is the entire method

```
    private static int[] bar(String []a)
{
    int [] tmp = new int[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i<a.length;i++)
    {
        tmp[i] = a[i].length();
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

This is what I have tried to do to call the method and print the answer.

```
    String [] a = {"hey", "how", "are", "you"};
    System.out.println(bar(a));
```

Comment: return the size of each word, and by the way it's not the memory address, it's just the name of the class followed by the hashcode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method creates an array of sizes of the parameters.
So for `["hey", "how", "are", "you"]` it will give back `[3, 3, 3, 3]`.

An easy way to print an array nicely is `Arrays.toString`:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bar(a)));
```

> What I have done just prints a memory address I think.

No. What you saw was the result of the `toString` method of the array.
Arrays inherit the default implementation of `Object.toString`,
which is classname + "@" + hexadecimal representation of the hashcode.